# NextJS 13 Client Component seems to load the server loading.jsx

Tags: next.js, next.js13

In my following NextJS13 Search Books component (I marked it as a client component), whenever I type in the search input field, the loading component keeps appearing at every onChange.

```
'use client';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import LoadingPage from "../loading";

async function getBooks() {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/books");
    const json = await res.json();
    return json;
}

const Books = async () => {
    const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        getBooks().then((books) => {
            setBooks(books);
            setLoading(false);
        });
    },[]);

    //if(loading){ return <LoadingPage />}

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(query);
        //const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/books/search", {
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search Books..." value={query} onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)} className="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs" />
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            </form>
            {books.map((book) => (
                <div key={book.id}>
                    <div className="card w-96 bg-base-100 shadow-xl">
                        <figure>
                            <img src={book.img} width="200" height="150" />
                        </figure>
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <h2 className="card-title">{book.id}</h2>
                            <p>{book.title}</p>
                            <div className="card-actions justify-end">
                                <Link href={book.link} className="btn btn-primary">See in Amazon</Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>                    
                    </div> 
                    <br />
                </div>              
            ))}           
        </div>
    )
}

export default Books;
```

The loading page comes from the loading.jsx in my /app folder:

```
const LoadingPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button className="btn loading">loading</button>
        </div>
    )
}
export default LoadingPage;
```

I am puzzled at why this is happening, as I thought client components won't load the loading pages.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution to this ! In my case, the component trigerring the loading was marked as async function.

I went from this : `export default async function Component() {}`

To this : `export default function Component() {}`

The loader is not triggered now and everything works properly.